# Nested Material UI Classes Data grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

I am trying to change the width of the rendering-zone in the nested material UI data grid component but after using `makeStyles` I cant get it to work. I have added the following makestyles but its getting ignored, I am not sure what is wrong.

[image]
[image]

I have the current table view:
[image]

But I want it to look like this:
[image]

and the only way of doing this is changing the width of the style in "rendering-zone" to auto.